# troubleshooting serial settings through stty

Tags: yocto, stty

#### Hardware

[PHYTEC Mira Board](http://www.phytec.eu/product/single-board-computer/phyboard-mira/) with **i.MX6** Processor

#### Operating System

Yocto Image created using the BSP provided by PHYTEC<sub>[Source](https://wiki.phytec.com/display/public/PRODUCTINFO/phyBOARD-Mira+i.MX6+Linux+Quickstart+PD15.2.0#phyBOARD-Mirai.MX6LinuxQuickstartPD15.2.0-BuildingBSPfromSourceBuildingtheBSPfromSource)</sub> with minimal packages in it.

The board has an UART board called **UART3** and its software interface within the OS is `/dev/ttymxc2` [Hardware Manual](http://www.phytec.eu/fileadmin/user_upload/downloads/Manuals/L-843e_0.pdf). The only thing available to check/set serial port on board is `stty`.

#### Task

I wish to interface an [Adafruit Ultimate GPS](https://www.adafruit.com/product/746) to the **UART3** to read information from it on the Mira Board.

**Attempt-1**

I connected both components in the following manner.

```
UART3_RXD_RS232 (MIRA) --> TX pin (GPS)
UART3_TXD_RS232 (MIRA) --> RX pin (GPS)
```

Set the serial port as follows:

```
 stty -F /dev/ttymxc2 speed 9600
```

Read value:

```
 cat /dev/ttymxc2
```

*Result*: Garbage Values. Tried all possible settings and still obtained garbage values. Wrote a simple `node` script to try to read the information coming from the port but I got error stating that the characters (garbage values) are not recognized.

**Attempt-2**

Initially I tried to connect the GPS to a simple Arduino Nano to obtain the values from the GPS and this works, confirming that the GPS sends information and no defect occurred.

I connect the Serial Ports of the Mira and the Arduino and try to send information from the Mira to the Arduino's serial interface and read it through serial console.

**setup**

```
   MIRA_Board (serial UART3) ---> Arduino Nano (Serial Pins) --USBCable--> Computer
```

**Pins**

```
 UART3_RXD_RS232 (MIRA) --> RX PIN NANO
 UART3_TXD_RS232 (MIRA) --> TX PIN NANO
```

I am logged into the Mira board through SSH. The following command is triggered, hoping to expect the same value on the computer's serial console through the Arduino

```
 echo 'hello' > /dev/ttymxc2
```

*Result*: Still Garbage Values on the Console.
[image: Result on Putty]

The configuration for `/dev/ttymxc2` is as

```
stty -F /dev/ttymxc2 -a                       
speed 9600 baud;stty: /dev/ttymxc2 line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;   -parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal –crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8  
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0   
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

If this issue is due to serial configuration mismatch, how do I troubleshoot it using `stty`?

**P.S.**: Baud rate for GPS should be `9600` which is the case

Comment: According to the documents you linked, the Mira board's UART3 uses standard RS-232 signal levels, whereas the GPS module uses 3 V signal levels. These are not compatible, and may even damage the GPS module.

Comment: Ah! That could be a strong factor. Are there any GPS modules that do provide 5V outputs? Might look into it. Thanks

Comment: You could try using UART1 or UART2 on the Mira board. According to the manual they use TTL level signals. The GPS module outputs 3 V, but tolerates 5 V on input. The +3 V should be enough to be interpreted as a "1" on a TTL input. The RS-232 signals are not suitable without a buffer, because RS-232 specifies +3..+12 V for the space state and -3..-15 V (that's **minus** 15 V) for the mark state.

Comment: Oh My God @JohanMyréen you are a savior. Thank you for figuring it out ! it took me days to solve this issue. Perhaps you can write the above mentioned comment as an answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using UART1 or UART2 on the Mira board. According to the manual they use TTL level signals. The GPS module outputs 3 V, but tolerates 5 V on input. The +3 V should be enough to be interpreted as a "1" on a TTL input. The RS-232 signals are not suitable without a buffer, because RS-232 specifies +3..+12 V for the space state and -3..-15 V (that's **minus** 15 V) for the mark state.

Comment: UART 2 (`/dev/ttymxc1`) is mainly used for debugging. so I tried connecting the GPS to it. I do get some results but the board restarted. I might have to look into UART1(`ttymxc0`) but that requires pin muxing and some more software work.